# disabling a page from being clickable

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

It's a rather odd question, but it worths a shot.
I am trying to make some sort of a game that runs on web pages, Your goal is to get to a certain webpage on a specif website starting a random webpage at the same website, using only hyperlinks.

```
def seaching_loop(start_point, goal):
while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    if goal.current_url == start_point.current_url:
        start_point.quit()
        goal.quit()
        break
```

This is the loop I am using to search if this condition is true.
But the problem is, people, can manipulate the "destination page" and press hyperlinks on it, which affects the goal. In addition to it - The search bar isn't disabled, meaning people can just search for the value they need.

I am using Selenium to **scrape** down the website, but I'm open-minded about using any other library/programing language you recommend.

BTW: I had an idea to take a screenshot of the page, out of the URL entered, but is it possible?

Update :

```
def seacrhing_loop(start_point, goal):
pure_goal = goal.current_url
start_point_temp = start_point.current_url
while True:
    if pure_goal != goal.current_url:
        goal.get(pure_goal)
        print("I am the goal, you cannot change me")
    if start_point_temp != start_point.current_url:
        start_point_temp = start_point.current_url
        if goal.current_url == start_point.current_url:
            start_point.quit()
            goal.quit()
            break
```

Now, whenever he changes the goal site, it brings him back. But still, the search engine is clickable. I have found the library Pyqt5 web, is it more suitable for those types of programs?

Thank you guys

Comment: the part about screenshot is very possible, You could try using `pyautogui` or maybe `Pillow` for that

Comment: I have looked into Pillow / pyautogui, but only found the option to take a screenshot of my current screen, not from a specific URL. But Ill search more in depth now

Comment: first of how do You expect to take a screenshot of something that is not on Your screen? don't think that is possible, second I was thinking of somehow monitoring the outgoing requests and if then You catch a url that shouldn't be there, immediately send a request to go back, basically request the previous page

Comment: I have just realized how stupid of me to think of taking a screenshot without the screen lol,
This idea sort of solving the problem, that I will just close the program whenever my starting point URL change(with an assert error ofc), but isn't it a too drastic measure and not user friendly? or do you mean that I should just whenever he clicks on another page it will just send him back to the starting page?

Comment: if the user has finished the "race" and You don't want them to continue, a simple option would be to close browser and display some message using GUI such as tkinter, what I meant is pretty similar to what You said about sending back, that is of course if the page the user went to is not where they were supposed to go.

Comment: @Matiiss I just posted the update :) your idea was brilliant and helped a lot , but still there is this annoying search bar :(

Comment: btw, if they search sth in the serach bar, does it still redirect them back? actually I just thought of an interesting way to not allow at least clicking in the search bar and that would be to make a topmost overrideredirect tkinter window that will stay in that place therefore it shouldn't be possible for the user to click with mouse there, then You have to deal with tabs, so You could use some library such as `keyboard` to make the tab key do nothing or sth? otherwise I can only again suggest that any request when the end is reached is not allowed, i.e. they get redirected back

Comment: or alternatively create Your own "browser" for this specific task, like don't make a search bar at all, I think it shouldn't be tooo hard since there are some modules that can display html and You can use `requests` to get the actual html and then just display it

Comment: I'm trying to contact you through chat but it's not possible for some reason :) I would really love it if you can elaborate a bit more because I wanted to use TK regardless to add a intro page with buttons and stuff :)

Comment: [https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235022/disabling-a-page-from-being-clickable]

Comment: I'm still new so i don't have any  reputation :(

Comment: unfortunately i am stuck yet unable to solve this problem, I am trying to wrap the web browser using Tkinter/PyQt but there is no solid docs

Comment: try making the topmost overrideredirect window, maybe that helps

Comment: @Matiiss I can finally use a room , so if its possible to private chat I would very much appreciate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235030/discussion-between-matiiss-and-jeff-style).